# TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, psycopg2

I am having difficulty querying all data from a table during the last 24hrs and it is difficult to say if its a postgres error on my part of python since im a beginner

I see the "publishedAt" field, returns a datetime.datetime value.

```
# print out columns names
cur.execute(
    """
    SELECT *
    FROM "table"
    LIMIT 1
    """
)

# print out columns names
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
print(colnames)

# print out col values
rows = cur.fetchall()
print(rows)

['id', 'publishedAt', ......]
[['5a086f56-d080-40c0-b6fc-ee78b08aec3d', datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 11, 
15, 39, 58, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=0, name=None)), .....]
```

However,

```
cur.execute(
    """
    SELECT * 
    FROM "table"
    WHERE publishedAt BETWEEN %s and %s;""", 
    (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1))
)
```

results in:

```
TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object does not support indexing
```

is it possible to use datetime library in psycopg2 queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you want to pass a tuple into `cur.execute()`, you're passing a single value (which is different from a "tuple" containing a single value)

also, why not do the date/time stuff in Postgres, it's pretty good at handling it.  e.g. your query could be something like:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE publishedAt > now() - interval '1 day'""")
```

otherwise you could do date calculations in the database with:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE publishedAt > %s - interval '1 day'""", (dt.datetime.now(),))
```

(notice the extra comma at the end), or do the calculation in Python with:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE publishedAt > %s""", (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1),))
```

if you want an upper limit on dates, you'd probably want to do something like:

```
now =  dt.datetime.now()
cur.execute("""SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE publishedAt BETWEEN %s AND %s""", (now - dt.timedelta(days=1), now))
```

(note that Python knows the brackets indicate a tuple so no trailing comma is needed)

Comment: right! amazing thanks for the detailed response...it clarifies a lot of guessing and checking ... so i just got this to work: cur.execute("""SELECT *
               FROM  "table" 
               WHERE "publishedAt" BETWEEN %s and %s;""", 
            (dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(day=1), dt.datetime.now()))

Comment: I like the idea of using the DB to do the datemath.  It is typically easier for debugging if you form the query, print it, then execute it.  That makes it much easier to get the quoting correct.